# Hiding #DIV/0! Errors Using IF and COUNTIF in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm working on a tracking sheet for quality reviews of work completed. I have a list of criteria to be met for which the entry can be either `Y` or `N`, or `X` for not applicable. Each month a number of these reviews will be done on each person.

In order to evaluate trending data I came up with a formula to return a percentage of times an `N` appears, for each criteria.

The sheet is set up as follows:

```
criteria   review 1   review 2
criteria 1  |Y|         |N|
criteria 2  |Y|         |Y|
criteria 3  |N|         |X|
criteria 4  |X|         |N|
```

I want to total the number of responses for each month and for each criterion which include a Y or N - basically to exclude all X responses from the total used to average.

What I came up with is this:

```
=(COUNTIF('Sheet 3'!B4:F4,"N"))/(COUNTIF('Sheet 3'!B4:F4,"Y")+(COUNTIF('Sheet3'!B4:F4,"N")))
```

The problem is where all criteria for a given month are `X`, this formula returns a `#DIV/0!` error. I've tried using an `IF` statement to solve for that, but I keep getting either **too many**, or **too few** argument errors. I asked if the count of `Y` and `N > 0`, then run that formula. If not, show `0`. That didn't work, I'm guessing because of how convoluted it all got.

Any suggestions? I'd like to avoid using additional columns to subtotal things if at all possible.

Comment: Does this work, basically take whole formula encapsulate in if/iserror and is true put 0 =IF(ISERROR((COUNTIF('Sheet 3'!B4:F4,"N"))/(COUNTIF('Sheet 3'!B4:F4,"Y")+(COUNTIF(Sheet3!B4:F4,"N")))),0,(COUNTIF('Sheet 3'!B4:F4,"N"))/(COUNTIF('Sheet 3'!B4:F4,"Y")+(COUNTIF(Sheet3!B4:F4,"N"))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider the following formula to resolve your issue:

```
=IFERROR((COUNTIF('Sheet 3'!B4:F4,"N"))/(COUNTIF('Sheet 3'!B4:F4,"Y")+(COUNTIF('Sheet3'!B4:F4,"N"))),0)
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your existing formula in the `IFERROR` function:

```
=IFERROR(COUNTIF('Sheet 3'!B4:F4,"N"))/(COUNTIF('Sheet 3'!B4:F4,"Y")+(COUNTIF('Sheet3'!B4:F4,"N")),"X")
```

where "X" is what will get shown if an error results from the calcualtion. Replace "X" with something else as required, e.g. 0, "n/a"

Comment: Thanks! Almost worked, but I got a 'too few arguments' error. nbayly's comment above worked, I think it's exactly the same but has an extra parenthesis...